# To post a message to a remote Queue using Web-Logic

Tags: jms, weblogic

I have gained some knowledge on consuming messages that are posted to a resource. In the process I used a stand-alone which posts messages to the local queue. Now, the task is to post messages to a remote queue, which resides in a server(say TIBCO), other than Web-Logic, which I use here.

My question is :
a) Are there any notable differences to be taken care of, when posting to a remote queue?

Comment: Queue location is based on the broker, not the producer or consumer. If the address of the broker is `localhost`, the queue is local, if it's anything else, it's remote.

Comment: thanku. I have been using Web-logic and never got a chance to explicitly deal with brokers. But my question is for posting a message to a resource sitting on a different server.

Comment: Would you like to accept the answer or let us know if this is not the answer you were looking for? or at least share the solution with us if you have resolved your issues. IMHO it is rude not to acknowledge if you are receiving some help from community.

Comment: I answered, to the post below. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Sending a message to a remote server is pretty simple. All you need is the URL of the remote server and the port number on which the JMS provider is listening for the incoming connections. Once you have these details then you do a JNDI Lookup for the Queue and establish a Session to send out the message. Something like below:

```
// Provide the details of remote JMS Server
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "mq://localhost:7676");

// Create the initial context for remote JMS server
InitialContext cntxt = new InitialContext(props);
System.out.println("Context Created");

// JNDI Lookup for QueueConnectionFactory in remote JMS Provider
QueueConnectionFactory qFactory =   (QueueConnectionFactory)cntxt.lookup("TestQueueConnectionFactory");

// Create a Connection from QueueConnectionFactory
Connection connection = qFactory.createConnection();
System.out.println("Connection established with JMS Provide ");
```

See this [JMS Client Server Example](http://techtipsjava.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/jms-on-glassfish-queue-and-topic-with.html) for full code details. I am guess you are only interested in the client code from this example.

Comment: thanks for the reply. But, when I pointed out,  as "notable differences", I meant, the extra points to be taken care of. Yes, in my research, I found that depending on the availability of the remote target, Messaging Bridges, are a way better to go with.

Comment: Apologies if my reply is too late, I am not a regular user of SO and do try to help whenever I find some time. You may have already figured it out, but the answer is that **there is no difference in terms of how you process the local or remote Queues**. It will be just the different URL, for local it will be local host and for remote it will be the Name of that server where the broker is running. However, all the other inherent problems are there, i.e. security, reliability, etc. which are common to communicating with any remote server.

Comment: You don't really need a message bridge to establish communication between a JMS Client and Provider. Message Bridge is more suitable in situations where you want to establish a communication mechanism between two channels, i.e., servers. So for instance when you want to send a message to multiple servers (not clients). Another reason maybe when you want to implement some customer pre-processing, i.e. use the bridge as a interceptor. If you simply want to establish message provider/consumer relationship then there is no need to add further complexity to your system.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to achieve?
If you simply want to post a message to a queue on any JMS compliant broker i would give a try to the Hermes Tool: http://www.hermesjms.com/confluence/display/HJMS/Home

Cheers

Comment: I meant a remote queue sitting on a different Application Server. I found the options I have to continue with, like Messaging Bridge etc.  Many Thanks!!!